# Is C# string passed by value or passed by reference?

Tags: c#, class, mutable, ref

```
namespace Test
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      A a = new A();
      a.MyString = "Metallica ";
      PrintA(a);
      Console.WriteLine(a.MyString);

      string name = "Linkin ";
      Print(name);
      Console.WriteLine(name);

      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void PrintA(A a)
    {
      a.MyString = a.MyString + "Rocks";
      Console.WriteLine(a.MyString);
    }

    static void Print(string text)
    {
      text = text + "Park";
      Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
  }

  class A
  {
    public string MyString { get; set; }
  }

}
```

Output:

> Metallica Rocks
>
> Metallica Rocks
>
> Linkin Park
>
> Linkin

My question here is that, if string is a reference type (i.e. a class) then why does it not change value of the variable *name* after the method *Print()* is called, like it happens for reference variable *a*'s member *MyString*.

Comment: "reference type" does not mean that it would be passed by reference.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, String is a reference type. It is passed by reference. However, when you make a change to the string value, another new copy is created of it leaving the original one unchanged. This is why it acts as if it is being sent by value

Comment: No. Pass by value vs pass by reference and value type vs reference types are completely different subjects. They are not related.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Strings are a reference type, but he reference is passed by value. It also is not copied when you make a change, but instead a new string is created and assigned to the reference; because the reference was passed by value the change is not reflected to the caller.